# updating branches using git pull

Tags: git

```
git version 1.7.3.5
```

I have the following branches:

```
git branch
  image
  master
* video
```

I did some work at the office. And when I came home I always update on my home's notebook.

However, when I did a `git remote show origin` I get the following:

```
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    image   pushes to image  (up to date)
    master  pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
    video   pushes to video  (local out of date)
```

So I did a git pull for all of these branches:

```
git pull origin image
git pull origin master
git pull origin video
```

When I do a git status on the video and image branch I get:

```
 nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

When I do a git status on the master branch I get:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
```

Which I don't understand the following `(fast-forwardable)` and `(local out of date)`?

But in the git status for video it saids its up to date?

Do I need to push my master if it is ahead by 5 commits?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: run `git log --stat --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative origin/master..master` to get an impression about the difference. `(fast-forwardable)` means it is safe to push: branches have the same commits except one branch (`local` in your cases) has some additional commits on top.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`git remote show origin` compares your local repository with the remote:

- `fast-forwardable` means you can push your local changes to the remote branch.
- `local out of date` means your local branch is behind the remote branch and you should pull from it.

`git status` compares your local working directory with the current commit of the current branch (aka `HEAD`). Additionally it compares your local branch with the (local!) tracking copy of the remote branch (`origin/master`), hence the `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.`

To solve the divergence between `git status` (which shows only local data) and `git remote show origin` (which shows "live" remote data) you should run `git remote update origin` which will update your local tracking branches. It will update your local `origin/master` to the state of the remote's `master`. After that `git status` should give you something like 
`Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by X commits, and can be fast-forwarded.`

Comment: If I get `Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by X commits, and can be fast-forwarded.` then what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `git pull origin master` to get your local `master` up-to-date.